# Excluding ContentPlaceHolder from generated ID tags

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have just implemented master page to control all my sub pages from a old project.

---

I had to add `<asp:content id="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">` to all my sub pages in order for them to be rendered correctly.

Some particular functionalities of my page include javascript calls from a `Button` with commands in an example below:

`<asp:button id="cmdReturn" runat="server" causesvalidation="False" cssclass="fontSize90" meta:resourcekey="cmdReturnResource1" text="Cancel" width="152px" />`

---

With the new `ContentPlaceHolder`, the javascript generated will not be compatible with my functions since it tacks on the `ContentPlaceHolder1` infront of all my JS calls like the example below

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdReturn" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirm_notsaved(&#39;eng&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdReturn" class="fontSize90" style="width:152px;" />`

Notice the `name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdReturn"`. I want to exclude the ContentPlaceHolder section of the name so, when generated, it turns into:

`name="cmdReturn"`

Is this possible after I have added the masterpage? I don't think I have access to the class/script that generates the HTML in the end result.

What could I do in this case to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add [`ClientIDMode="Static"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your `<asp:Button...` tag.